# Run a jQuery function after browse 3 pages

Tags: jquery

I would like to run a javascript function with Jquery on the user, but only when he browse 3 pages on the site. Does anyone know if it is possible to do this? And how?

Comment: I think you'd need to keep track of that on the server side. Although, maybe you could have the 3 "pages" run inside of a frame...

Comment: 3 specific pages, or just third visit to the site?

Comment: Could use local storage.

Comment: Specifically 3 pages after browsing the site, because I would like to display an element that is intrusive, then the user would be interested in to view this content element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the count in `localStorage`.

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var count = localStorage.getItem('pageCount');
        if (!count) {
            count = 1;
        } else {
            count++;
        }

        localStorage.setItem('pageCount', count);

        if(count === 3) {
            theFunctionYouWantToCall();
        }
    });

    function theFunctionYouWantToCall() {
        // do some javascript/jQuery stuff
    }
}(jQuery));
```

If you wanna use localStorage **and** have a cookie fallback, you can use my [cache library](https://github.com/jkempff/cachejs).

Comment: Hello Juk, and if i use a jquery function in the "theFunctionYouWaitToCall, for exemple... like: 
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#exemple').delay(100).fadeIn('medium');
});

Comment: You should **not** use jQuery.ready here! The `ready` only tells javascript to wait for all the document to be loaded. If you need to wait for the document, put all the code into the ready function. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I never used local storage, im searching about this now.
But, can i use local storage + jquery with cookies?

Comment: `localStorage` is a client side "key-value" store. You can check its support on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#localStorage)

Comment: Beautiful solution. You should go for this lago!

Comment: I'm trying, but I'm not managing to make it work correctly in my example that already has jquery cookies.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help. After some tests, I managed to make it work perfectly. He recorded a local store here and I have not needed to use jquery cookies to make it not open more after the third visit too.

Comment: For the record: Not every browser supports `localStorage`. If you want to use localStorage *and* wanna be sure it works also with javascript cookies, you should have a look on my "Cache" library, that uses localStorage and has a built in fallback to jQuery.cookie: [https://github.com/jkempff/cachejs](https://github.com/jkempff/cachejs)

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of visited pages using session state or url parameters

Answer (score 2):

You could use cookies.  A quick Google search should result in a good number of jQuery Cookie plugins.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using a jQuery function that uses cookies to check if the user has already seen this element. So would you use two cookies, there would be compatibility issues?

Comment: Depends what function you're using to check cookies, but you should be able to use multiple cookies.  Here's an example of one way to do it: http://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/

Comment: Thank you. I'll search more about multiple cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming three *unique* page visits:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    var c = JSON.parse($.cookie('visitsToPage') || '[]');

    if (c.indexOf(window.location.href) == -1) c.push(window.location.href);

    if (c.length == 3){
      // this is third visit--do something
    }

    $.cookie('visitsToPage', JSON.stringify(c));
  });
</script>
```

Of course this could be refactored to use localStorage, but I'll leave that up to you.